# Center items in a division (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I am new in learning web development and having a question about how to center items in a div. I was wondering why we set "text-align:center" to center all a-tag items in div instead set the text-align in a tag?

```
<div>
  <a href="">ONE</a>
  <a href="">TWO</a>
  <a href="">THREE</a>
  <a href="">FOUR</a>
  <a href="">FIVE</a>
</div>
```

---

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

div {
  background-color: #ffa;
  text-align:center; //correct one
}

div a {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px #aaa solid;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center; // wrong one
}
```

Comment: you have no `<p>` inside `<div>`

Comment: @Banzay Sorry for the typo

Comment: as you set `display:inline-block;` for `a` it will take width of its content, once you chenge this attribute value to `block`, then it will take 100% width of line and `text-align` start to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Samuel pointed out, you first need to close your div. In addition to that, the default `display` property of `<a>` tags is `inline`. So your code will line them up, and center them in the parent div.

If you want to stack them up, you'll need to set `display:block`.

Note that by default the width will be 100% of the parent div. Set a specific width and `margin:auto` if you don't want those `<a>` tags to go from left to right of the parent.

See all examples here: https://jsfiddle.net/82hnvpg9/

On a side note, `//` isn't the correct way to add comments to CSS. Use `/* Comment */` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Please correct me if I am wrong. So, if we want to layout edition to all child items, we have to set the attribute in the parent selector instead of child selector? Or it depends on what element we use?

Comment: CSS properties apply to whatever you give them to. In your case, you can set text-align:center to <a> tags instead and it would work just the same, except if <a> tags are set to display:inline. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/k7vasczb/

Comment: The reason for this is text-align inherits from the property of its parent. So if you set it for the parent, it also applies to the child unless you specify otherwise, but this isn't true for all CSS properties.

Comment: If you open Chrome's dev tools (or any other browser's), you'll see the properties that are inherited from the element's parent. In your example, you'll get this if you set text-align to the parent only: https://i.ibb.co/mywcHr7/Annotation-2020-04-11-122506.png

Answer (score 0):

Amy, the reason why is because there are no p tags wrapping the text in your links. This means that even if you were to include text-align: center; as a style for p tags it would not apply to that text.

Comment: Sorry, there's a typo for the question. It should be a tag.

Answer (score 0):

There are no p tags. so you can use div tag i think.
If you want to make p tags center, you have to adjust style attribute

```
display: inline-block
```

or

```
display:inline
```

because p tags are a block element. 
Basically, all block elements have parents' width. so you can't make '100% width' element center.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no `<p>` tag in the `<div>` so the CSS for div p { } won't work apply.
Now, if you used:

```
div **a** {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px #aaa solid;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

it would apply the CSS to your HTML, however, it still wouldn't center the items in the div - it would **only** center the text inside the `<a>` element.
That is why in order to center items inside the container you can apply text-align: center to the parent `<div>`:

```
div {
  background-color: #ffa;
  text-align: center;
}
```